# How to run a steady state dynamics, Modal step based optimisation using TOSCA?

Tags: dynamics, abaqus, modal-analysis

What design responses must be given in the TOSCA gui. I chose volume reduction as an objective function with the constraints of displacement. Is this approach correct?